# The multi-part identifier "AD.primary_name" could not be bound

Tags: sql, sql-server

It is showing the multi-part identifier could not be bound error in the join. please let me know the solution.

```
SELECT BI.bl_nbr, 
       BI.cv_nbr, 
       AD.acct_cv_id, 
       AD.primary_name, 
       BI.[primary], 
       CASE 
         WHEN Ltrim(Rtrim(AD.primary_name)) IS NULL THEN 
         Ltrim(Rtrim(BI.[primary])) 
         ELSE ( AD.primary_name ) 
       end 
FROM   [dbo].[stg_acct_detail_us] AD, 
       [dbo].[stg_bi_fnl2] BI 
       JOIN [dbo].[stg_bi_fnl2] ON AD.primary_name = [dbo].[stg_bi_fnl2].[primary] 
where AD.acct_cv_id = BI.cv_nbr
```

Comment: Never use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use explicit `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: Scope rules. Join chains are evaluated before comma separated tables. The AD columns aren't available yet.

Comment: replace `, [dbo].[stg_bi_fnl2] BI ` with `JOIN [dbo].[stg_bi_fnl2] BI ON AD.acct_cv_id = BI.cv_nbr`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT BI.bl_nbr, 
       BI.cv_nbr, 
       AD.acct_cv_id, 
       AD.primary_name,  
       CASE 
         WHEN Ltrim(Rtrim(AD.primary_name)) IS NULL THEN 
         Ltrim(Rtrim(BI.[primary])) 
         ELSE ( AD.primary_name ) 
       end 
FROM   [dbo].[stg_acct_detail_us] AD 
       JOIN [dbo].[stg_bi_fnl2] BI ON AD.PRIMARY_NAME = BI.[primary] 
where AD.acct_cv_id = BI.cv_nbr
```